# zip encryption on the ipad

Tags: ipad, encryption, zip

Is there a support for zip with encryption on the iPad? Also, looks like there are security flaws in using zip with encryption. Could you someone give some information on this?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 2):

ZIP's default encryption indeed has security problems (weak encryption used). WinZIP and PKZip independently offered their own stronger encryption mechanisms. WinZIP offered only symmetric (AES-based) encryption, while PKZip also offers certificate-based encryption (but only within their own products - third-parties are allowed to only decrypt files encrypted with certificates).

Answer (score 1):

Zip old-style decryption is definitely weak, however new implementations (WinZIP and others) can use AES for encryption. And, as well there is a lot of open source implementations (InfoZIP for instance) which can be used on iPhone, and support that encryption type.